# How can I sort n words with length k in linear time?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science

I want to implement an algorithm to sort n words of length k, the words will contain only English words (so from a-z).

I tried to use the counting sort by casting the first element of the word -> character to its integer representation and then use Counting Sort (Linear Time Sorting), this kind of works but it is only sorting the first character i.e when two or more words have the same first character then they are not sorted by their second character?

Can someone guide me or give me a hint for another approach which will let me sort these n words in linear time?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: Radix sort's run time is linear in `nk`.  Bucket sort can be implemented with linear expected run time, also in `nk`. It's misleading to characterize them as "linear in `n`" without qualification that key length is fixed.

Comment: @Gene strictly speaking, nowhere does the author say that it should be linear in n, and no answers or comments claim this either.

Answer (score 1):

[Radix sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/radix-sort/) is probably the way to go - it will stable sort each word by the i-th letter. Since you're working with characters, you're essentially already working in the appropriate radix!